# What is the short form of Valkyrie?

Tags: language

Imagine I have a female character named [Valkyrie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valkyrie) in an English text. What could a short form of that name be (analogous to *Bob* for *Robert*) ?

I could only come up with

- Vally
- Val

Comment: Not entirely sure this is on topic...

Comment: How about Kerri?

Comment: Marvel has a character with that name, or actually a bunch of related characters (the same essence kept getting dumped into different human women in the 80s). IIRC, she was originally named “The Valkyrie”, and usually nicknamed “Valk”., but when she became just “Valkyrie”, sometimes she was “Val”. More recently, there’s a movie version in Thor: Ragnarok, but I don’t remember anyone using a nickname for her.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Valerie sounds like a real name that is very close to the original word. (I would not be surprised if this is where the name comes from, even)

It is usually shorted to "Val" as well.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valerie_%28given_name%29